# Issue with getting a tcp C# server communicate to a java client

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have been working on trying to get my C# server communicate to my java client program. The problem is that the C# server can not send info through the stream to the java client. The thing is I am able to get info from the java client program. I know with the files and having a multi-threaded server could make it more confusing. But first here is the code:

C# server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project
{
class TcpServerCode
{
    private List<clientHolder> clientHolderList = new List<clientHolder>();
    private TcpListener _server;
    private Boolean _isRunning;

    public TcpServerCode(int port)
    {
        _server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        _server.Start();

        _isRunning = true;

        if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM"))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM");
        }


        Thread th = new Thread(this.LoopClients);
        th.Start();
    }

    public void LoopClients()
    {
        while (_isRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                // wait for client connection
                TcpClient newClient = _server.AcceptTcpClient();


                // client found.
                // create a thread to handle communication
                Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClient));
                clientHolder ch = new clientHolder();
                ch.generateRandomName();
                ch._tcp = newClient;
                clientHolderList.Add(ch);
                t.Start(ch);
            }
            catch(Exception i)
            {
                Log.handleException(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public  void HandleClient(object obj)
    {
        // retrieve client from parameter passed to thread
        clientHolder client = (clientHolder)obj;

        // sets two streams
        //StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(client._tcp.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        NetworkStream ns = client._tcp.GetStream();
        client._tcp.GetStream().ReadTimeout = 100;
        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(client._tcp.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

        // you could use the NetworkStream to read and write, 
        // but there is no forcing flush, even when requested

        Boolean bClientConnected = true;
        String sData = null;

        Task getter = null;
        Task sender = null;
        while (bClientConnected)
        {
            if (getter != null)
            {
                if (getter.IsCompleted)
                {
                    getter = _get(sReader, client.clientName);
                }
            }
            else
            {

                getter = _get(sReader, client.clientName);
            }


            if (sender != null)
            {
                if (sender != null)
                {
                    sender = _send(ns, client.clientName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sender = _send(ns, client.clientName);
            }





            /* if (sender != null)
             {
                 if(sender.IsCompleted)
                 {
                     sender = _send(ns, client.clientName);
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 sender = _send(ns, client.clientName);
             }*/
        }
    }

    public int getServerClientCount()
    {
        try
        {
            List<clientHolder> tempClientHolder = new List<clientHolder>();
            foreach(clientHolder ch in clientHolderList)
            {
                if(ch._tcp.Connected)
                {
                    tempClientHolder.Add(ch);
                }
            }
            clientHolderList = tempClientHolder;
            return clientHolderList.Count;
        }
        catch(Exception i)
        {
            Log.handleException(i);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private static async Task _get(StreamReader reader, string clientName)
    {
        string sData = null;
        sData = await reader.ReadLine();


            // shows content on the console.
        if (sData != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_get.txt"))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_get.txt");
                }
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_get.txt", sData);
            }
            catch (Exception i)
            {
                Log.handleException(i);
            }

        }
    }


    private static async Task _send(NetworkStream ns, string clientName)
    {
        string[] nuller = { "one" };

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_send.txt"))
        {
            try
            {

                string info = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_send.txt");
                byte[] toSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(info);
                await ns.Write(toSend, 0, toSend.Length);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\_sent", nuller);
                System.IO.File.Delete(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_send.txt");

            }
            catch (Exception i)
            {
                Log.handleException(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public string getServerClientName(int index)
    {
        try
        {
            List<clientHolder> tempClientHolder = new List<clientHolder>();
            foreach (clientHolder ch in clientHolderList)
            {
                if (ch._tcp.Connected)
                {
                    tempClientHolder.Add(ch);
                }
            }
            clientHolderList = tempClientHolder;
            return clientHolderList[index].clientName;
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            Log.handleException(i);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public bool sendServerMessage(string clientName, string info)
    {
        try
        {



            if(System.IO.File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_send.txt"))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_send.txt");
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_send.txt", info);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_okToRead", info);
            return true;

        }
        catch(Exception i)
        {
            Log.handleException(i);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string getServerMessage(string clientName, string info)
    {
        try
        {
            if(System.IO.File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_get.txt"))
            {
                string results = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_get.txt");
                return results;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception i)
        {
            Log.handleException(i);
            return null;
        }
    }

}

public class clientHolder
{
    public TcpClient _tcp;
    public string clientName;

    public void generateRandomName()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        clientName = "Client_" + Convert.ToString(rand.NextDouble());
    }
}
```

Also here is the java client code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CoreServer {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +
            "running the date service on port 4444:");
    try{
        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 4444);
        ClientServerOutputReader csor = new ClientServerOutputReader(s);
        csor.start();

        ClientUserInputReader cuir = new ClientUserInputReader(s);
        cuir.start();

    } catch(UnknownHostException i){
        System.err.println("Don't know about host");
        System.err.println(i.getMessage());
    } catch(IOException i){
        System.err.println("couldn't get I/O for the connection");
        System.err.println(i.getMessage());
    }
}
}


class ClientServerOutputReader extends Thread {
Socket serverSocket;
public ClientServerOutputReader(Socket serverSocket){
    this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
        }

public void run() {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(serverSocket.getInputStream()));

        String outputFromServer="";
        while((outputFromServer=in.readLine())!= null){
            //This part is printing the output to console
            //Instead it should be appending the output to some file
            //or some swing element. Because this output may overlap
            //the user input from console
            System.out.println(outputFromServer);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

class ClientUserInputReader extends Thread {
Socket serverSocket;
public ClientUserInputReader(Socket serverSocket){
    this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
}
public void run(){
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    PrintWriter out;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(serverSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        String userInput;

        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The whole idea is to have a tcp listener then extracting the tcp client sending it through a thread to a callback like method, which it is assigned a client name with a random double on the end of the name. The way the thread communicates back to the main thread is through files, the files clientname_send.txt and clientname_get.txt is used to get and send messages to the client program. I bet there is a problem with the files, but for the most part I don't really get any exceptions. Thank you very much for anyone to help me out! I know it is a mess, I have been working on it all day and need some fresh eye's to look at it.

Comment: You are creating async tasks without any await. If you are creating the task expecting it to create a new thread that will be incorrect, if the task scheduler decides it's not worth to change of thread then it will be executed on the same one, and as you don't have any await the thread will be blocked until the task finishes, it can even cause a deadlock. I would recommend to just create a thread to continuously read from the networkstream and other thread to write as for what I can see the read and write on your logic is continuous.

Comment: I did add the await's in the code and it is still the same issue, but now more exceptions appear when trying to send info to the client, I will try to figure something out in the meanwhile.